# How to install Appium in ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, appium, ubuntu-16.04

I am very new to ubuntu,
I am trying to install appium in ubuntu 16.04,
I use these command to install appium in ubuntu, but installation is failed.

```
brew install node  
npm install -g appium
```

Comment: Can you share, error message you're getting.

Comment: > appium@1.6.5-beta prepublish /home/murali/appium
> gulp prepublish

sh: 1: gulp: not found

npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/murali/appium
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

Comment: As per your error message, I think gulp is not installed or may be its installed but not at global level. Try to install gulp with -g flag.

Comment: it's working now, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`brew` is a package manager for macOSX. On ubuntu you have to use [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
npm install -g appium
```

Comment: Perfect ! So don't forget to validate my answer ☺.